# Confusion on how to compile this android project

Tags: android-studio, github, compilation, project

I'm definitely what you could consider an android beginner and I would like to use the JamsMusicPlayer from github (https://github.com/psaravan/JamsMusicPlayer) and add some of my own features to it.

Now the problem im having is I have no experience with github and im not familiar with the android studio project structure. I downloaded the project as a zip and extracted.

When I open android studio im not sure which folder to open as a project, opening the JamsMusicPlayer-master or JamsMusicPlayer folder gives the error

```
Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a   network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires  network)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
```

Clicking on the re-download dependancies link has no effect.
My goal here is to compile it and run it on my phone and then start editing, not sure what to do with regards to dependancies/modules etc. they all seem to have their own project within the master project??

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some choices to run a project form GitHub:

1. extract the zip file and import the project from `file->new->import` Project and navigate the downloaded files

2.`File->new->Project From Version Controls` and  put the address from here

[image]